# Permission Issue and Incorrect Data Placement in Google Sheets Code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing my first code in Google Scripts. I'm encountering an issue with my code where it doesn't have the necessary permissions to access Google Sheets. I'm getting the error message "Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById" when trying to execute the code. The code is intended to modify and retrieve data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

In addition to the permission issue, there is a specific behavior in the code that needs to be addressed. The code is designed to transfer information to a specific row within the Google Sheets spreadsheet, but it is currently transferring the data to a location outside the spreadsheet. For example, if there is an empty space available in the spreadsheet at row 9, the code mistakenly transfers the information to a different location outside the table where there is no formatting or structure. I attached my code below

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var column = editedRange.getColumn();
  var row = editedRange.getRow();
  
  if (column > 1 && row > 1) {
    var technicianNameCell = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 13);
    var technicianName = technicianNameCell.getValue();
    var dataValues = [];
    
    var columnsToCopy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12]; // A, B, C, D, E, F, G, J
    
    for (var i = 0; i < columnsToCopy.length; i++) {
      var value = sourceSheet.getRange(row, columnsToCopy[i]).getValue();
      dataValues.push(value);
    }
    
    var targetSpreadsheetIds = {
      "technicianName": {
        "spreadsheetId": "spreadsheetId",
        "sheetName": "sheetName"
      },
      "technicianName": {
        "spreadsheetId": "spreadsheetId",
        "sheetName": "sheetName"
      },
      "technicianName": {
        "spreadsheetId": "spreadsheetId",
        "sheetName": "sheetName"
      }
    };
    
    var targetSpreadsheet = targetSpreadsheetIds[technicianName];
    
    if (targetSpreadsheet) {
      var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheet.spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(targetSpreadsheet.sheetName);
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      var firstEmptyRow = lastRow + 1;
      
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, 1, 1, dataValues.length);
      targetRange.setValues([dataValues]);
    }
  }
}
```

I attempted to implement a code that modifies and retrieves data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet. I expected the code to have the necessary permissions to access the spreadsheet and perform the required operations. Specifically, I expected the code to fill the empty space within the spreadsheet, with the transferred information while preserving the formatting and structure of the table.

However, what actually resulted was that the code encountered a permission issue. The error message "Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById" was displayed when executing the code. Additionally, the transferred information was placed in a location outside the table where there was no formatting or structure.

**Data Placement in Google Sheets Code**

Alright, so here's the deal. The code I'm using is pretty good at finding empty spots in the table. The only problem is, it ends up putting the data outside of the actual table that I have. You see, the code thinks that the formatting within the table is a complete line, so it doesn't place the data exactly where I want it to be within those lines.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEX0Z.png)

The code that I have right now

```js
function myEditTrigger(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    const [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, , , k, l, m] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    let vs = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, k, l];
    var tObjs = {
      "techname": {
        "spreadsheetId": "spreadsheetId",
        "sheetName": "sheetName"
      },
   
    };
    var tObj = tObjs[m];
    if (tObj) {
      var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tObj.spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(tObj.sheetName);
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, vs.length).setValues([vs]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using an installable trigger

Answer (score 0):

Use installable trigger and rename trigger function, do not use onEdit

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart > 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    const [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,,,,k,l,m] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1 , 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    let vs = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,k,l];
    var tObjs = {"technicianName": {"spreadsheetId": "spreadsheetId","sheetName": "sheetName" },...};//Hard code the objs or make them global
    var tObj = tObjs[m];
    if (tObj) {
      var tsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tObj.spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(tObj.sheetName);
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, vs.length).setValues(vs);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It helped to avoid permission issue. I appreciate your help a lot. 
By the way I'm still struggling with getting the data in the correct spot on the table. I'll reply to this thread and attach a screenshot to show you what I'm dealing with.

Comment: I've titled the issue in main text "Data Placement in Google Sheets Code" to make it easier to find. The details about the issue are at the end of main text. If you could spare a moment to take a look, I would be incredibly grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Cooper, what exactly I should describe in details for better comprehension?